# 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Tags: ios

```
May 24 16:12:49 unknown installd[138] <Error>: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
May 24 16:12:49 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Killing com.cequint.ims for termination assertion
May 24 16:12:50 unknown installd[138] <Error>: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
May 24 16:12:50 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Reloading application state for 'com.cequint.ims' as its modification date or path has changed
May 24 16:12:50 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
```

This has recently started appearing in the console, though none of my provisioning profiles have changed, and according to Xcode all the profiles are valid (there is an Apple Push Profile, a development profile, and a team provisioning profile).

I am having problems with notification badging counts not appearing and suspect that is related to this line:"Reloading and rendering all application icons."

Anybody have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the build settings for the target, select Code Signing, then Code Signing Identity, make sure the profile set for your build is the Apple Push Profile.