# Push notifications don't work if app is installed via iTunes but they do if installed by XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that uses push notifications and I am trying to distribute it to testers for testing.

If I create an ad-hoc distribution which gets installed via iTunes then everything works except for the push notifications, which never arrive.
But if the app is installed using XCode then the push notifications do arrive.

When I build for installation using XCode I set the code signing identity within XCode to my development profile. When I build for ad-hoc distribution I set the code signing identity within XCode to be the ad-hoc distribution profile when building the archive, then sign the archive for distribution again with the ad-hoc profile (I found this was the only combination that would allow installation via iTunes without an error message).

All the devices have been added to the ad-hoc distribution profile and to the apple push profile (and also to the team provisioning profile), the profiles have been renewed and refreshed within XCode.
Even with my own iPhone I can get push notifications to work if I install with XCode but not with iTunes.

Am I signing the ad-hoc distribution with the incorrect profiles, if so what is the correct combination of profiles? 
Is there another reason why the push notifications don't work for the ad-hoc distribution but do when the app is installed via XCode?

These are the profiles used:

```
1) Apple push profile which has an App id of abcdef.com.company.mno
2) Project Development profile which has an App id of abcdef.com.company.mno
3) iOS Team provisioning profile which has an app id of abcdef.*
4) AdHoc Distribution profile which has an app id of abcdef.com.company.mno
5) My developer profile which has an app id of abcdef.com.company.mno
```

** since first posting this I tried creating a new iOS Team provisioning profile using the abcdef.com.company.mno app id but it made no difference **

The abcdef.com.company.mno App Id is showing Push Notifications for Development as being enabled (which is correct, we are not yet using Production pushes). Also its Development Push SSL Certificate is showing as enabled.

The code signing identities are: first pic what I use for installing/running using XCode, 2nd picture when building an archive for ad hoc distribution.

[image]

[image]

The description for the iPhone Distribution profile in XCode says: "Ad Hoc distribution profile (for bundle identifiers com.company.mno)".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're probably signing the adhoc version with a wildcard app id provisioning profile.  Make sure the Code Signing Identity in the build settings is explicitly using your explicit-app-id provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks, however it looks like the adhoc profile is for an explicit app id (added details to the original posting) and not a wildcard?

Comment: Show the Code Signing Identity settings from the Xcode project (screenshot).  That would be really helpful.  If you're using "Automatic Profile Selector" it's probably picking the wrong one.  Xcode is kind of stupid in that way.  (I keep filing bugs about it but they have not fixed it yet.)

Comment: For the XCode build I'm manually setting all of them to the development profile, for the ad-hoc build I'm manually setting all of them to the ad-hoc profile. I'm not using the automatic selector. I'll post a screen shot in a few minutes.

Comment: Another thing I tried is creating a new iOS team provisioning profile which uses the specific app id rather than the wildcard one, but it made no difference.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing all the right things.  I'd create a new provisioning profile on the portal website, download it, and try that.

Comment: That did the trick. Is creating a new provisioning profile something that is *supposed* to be done whenever something changes such as adding a new device id, or is it supposed to update automatically?

Comment: Profiles do not update automatically. Profiles do contain a list of authorized device ids though, so I'm confused as to why it would even install on your device if it wasn't listed in the profile.

Comment: My and a few other devices were listed in the profile and had been so for many months, but there were also a few new devices added to the portal recently. However push would not work for *every* device when installed via iTunes, including ones that have been registered for a very long time. Next time I add new devices do I need to delete the old ad-hoc profile and create a new one (as opposed to refreshing/renewing it)? Is that the only profile that needs to be recreated each time new devices are added? Thanks

Comment: You can change the device list in a provisioning profile just by editing the profile in the portal. (Click Edit, then Modify). You don't have to delete it or renew it.  Note that you DO have to download the new profile, install it in Xcode, and distribute apps signed with the new profile! Existing apps don't magically update.

Comment: Yes I've been doing that. But apparently it wasn't working until I actually deleted the profile and created a brand new one from scratch. I wanted to check I wasn't *supposed* to delete it each time new devices are added, just edit the existing one. It seems I was doing things correctly but for some reason things got broken somehow. Thanks.

Comment: try my answer,it will 100% work if you set custom provision profile which u make for APNS iOS Development :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718985/why-my-archive-ipa-file-of-push-notification-app-didnt-work-on-device-instead-o/34725260#34725260

Answer (score 1):

This morning I had a similar issue trying to compile an In House app (I think it's the same issue). I had the iPhone plugged to the computer and I saw in console one warning like: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

I tried this solution, but I had no success:

['aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746627/aps-environment-has-value-not-permitted-by-a-provisioning-profile)

So, my app was working correctly in release mode running from Xcode, but when I tried to export with Ad Hoc certificate my iPhone shown that message on console.

Finally I went to profiles in iPhone and deleted all. I went to profiles in Organizer and deleted all too. I edited the provisioning profile via Provisioning portal and downloaded them again.

I changed code signing to Don't code sign. Changed again to In House provisioning profile, exported to a file and everything worked fine!

Comment: If you have "App Ad-hoc" profile selected on code signing and you make any change on provisioning profile, you have to select any other profile and select it again to refresh changes (so I selected Don't code sign and then select it again)

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to affect anything though. Are you using the ad-hoc profile to sign at both stages? I'm wondering if the iOS team provisioning profile needs to be abcdef.com.company.mno for push to work.

Comment: Yes. Did you try to add/delete some device to provisioning profile and then try again? As my answer said, I read in some threads that people is experimenting issues if they configure push on an App after creating provisioning profiles. This is why I told you to edit provisioning profile.

Comment: When you say edit the provisioning profile do you mean the ad-hoc profile or the iOS team provisioning profile. I've edited everything that can be edited on the portal, but for the iOS Team provisioning profile it says its managed by XCode and thus can't be edited.

Comment: I'm refering to ad-hoc profile. Did you check if your iPhone is telling something (just any warning or something) just when device is registering for push notifications (installing via Ad Hoc)?

Comment: No its fine (actually there are 6 devices, none of them work via iTunes, they all work via XCode). No error messages.

Comment: Is your iOS Team provisioning profile using a wildcard app id or a specific app id?

Comment: Specific app id, with wildcard doesn't work push notifications